# Ant build: works in terminal, fails in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, ant

I have a Java project developed in Eclipse. The project builds fine in Eclipse. Now I want to build it in Jenkins. From Eclipse, I have exported an Ant build.xml, which I have added to a Jenkins project. 
When I run the build in Jenkins it immediately generates an error. This is the (anonymised) console output:

> Started by user Admin User
>   Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Project1
>
> [projectname] $ ant -file build.xml class1.method1 class1.method2 Buildfile:
>   /home/ubuntu/eclipse-workspace/projectname/build.xml
>
> class1.method1:
>
> BUILD FAILED /home/ubuntu/eclipse-workspace/projectname/build.xml:91:
>   Could not create tempfile in /home/ubuntu/eclipse-workspace/projectname
>
> Total time: 4 seconds Build step 'Invoke Ant' marked build as failure
>   Finished: FAILURE

I copied the Ant command line from the console and ran it in a terminal window (in the folder where the build.xml exists) and it worked fine.

I am using Jenkins 2.60.2, Ant 1.9.6, Jenkins Ant plugin 1.5, Ubuntu 16.04.

I'm fairly new to working with these tools on Ubuntu but I guess it is something to do with either my Jenkins/Ant configuration or user permissions. What have I missed?

Comment: You need to changes the Paths in build.xml, because while executing others in Jenkins it has admin permission to run in the eclipse folder as it has some permissions in it. So try to change the Paths to other space and try it.